# How to programmatically edit Excel sheets?

Tags: python, linux, excel, editing

I need to edit an Excel workbook using python. Is there a way of doing this without reading in the workbook, editing what I want and the writing it back? i.e. is there a way I can do this on the fly, as I only need to edit a couple of values per sheet?

I have looked at `pyexcelerator`, `xlrd`, and `xlwt`, but they only seem to support (as far as I can work out) reading and writing not editing. I cannot use `pywin32` as I am using linux.

Any suggestions of libraries or particular ways of doing things?

Comment: Is this an xls or an xlsx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xlutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) has a copy module that may be interseting for you

Answer (score 9):

First off, what version of Excel? Excel2007+ use an XML file format, while Excel2003- used a proprietary binary format... so the tools to read and write these work in totally different ways.

If you're after the more recent xlsx files, then take a look at Eric' Gazoni's [openpyxl](http://ericgazoni.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/openpyxl-python-xlsx/) project. The code can be found on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/). The driving force behind this is the ability to read and write xlsx files from Python within a single library.

Even then, it reads the entire workbook, but allows you to modify cells before writing it back.

Simply put: the structure of an Excel file doesn't lend itself to easy editing.... it's not simply a case of changing a few characters.

Comment: its an xls file that I need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [pyexcelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) on linux to edit and build xls files